# Can't see my EC2 instances on the management console?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I'm a beginner to AWS and servers in general

I logged into AWS on laptop 1 and set up an EC2 instance. Next day I logged into AWS console on laptop 2, then the instance was gone. So I set up another EC2 instance to play with. Then logging into the console using a third laptop 3 the day after that, I found my first instance but not the second...

The second instance is still running as I can access the IP..

Any idea why this is happening? It's really confusing and annoying

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I found the answer.

I somehow ended up making multiple accounts under the same email address (don't ask). Didn't realise it was possible.

Anyway hope this helps

Answer (score 13):

The most likely explanation is that you have inadvertently switched region.  Look in the top right of the interface just to the right of your username.  Verify that you are in the region that you expect to be.

The EC2 instances can be placed in any of the regions, but you will only see the EC2 instances for the region that you are currently viewing.

Comment: I've seen this answer already but alas I don't think that's the problem (going to triple check in a moment)

Comment: Nope, definitely not fixed

Comment: Are you certain that you are logging in with the same account?

Comment: same email address. I don't understand :S Do you think there's another reason for it?

Comment: Yes, this answer helped me in solving mine, seems the region gets reset sometimes. choosing the right region brought back my instances.

Answer (score 0):

The same happened to me, aparenty I (or AWS) changed my region to N Virginia,  tracing my instances IP location yelded Oregon and voilá

Answer (score 0):

Right above the instances list there is a search field. There was a search parameter for the first instance that I created, After deleting it, my other instances all appeared.

[Picture of Instance List](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bujWK.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

The instance is running, but the console is set to a different region,

> Just change the region, it will work

Answer (score 0):

I happened to trace my EC2's public IP via https://whatismyipaddress.com/ and it shown some other location where it was not intended to do. I dont know how that happened, but anyway found it!